# connecting two android devices via TCP sockets

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I've been trying to connect two Android devices (2.1) via TCP sockets.
The vital part of the code:

Server:
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

Client:
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

The weird thing is I can make it work if the client is an emulator, but the same code fails if running both of them on real devices.
The failure in the client side is:

```
 
java.net.SocketException: No route to host
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectSocketImpl(Native
 Method)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.
java:114)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:
245)
     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:
220)
     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:780)
     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:314)
```

I tried with WIFI and mobile net too, they were in the same subnet both times, INTERNET permission is given, the server is addressed through its real 192.168.. IP.
I am planning to change the socket implementation with setCustomSocketImplFactory().
The problem is crucial in the process of implementing MSRP protocol to Android.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What do you mean by real IP if the programs are running on two mobile phones ?

Comment: I've just tried to say that the problem is not that I use 10.0.2.15 IP for the real devices

Answer (score 1):

Very few mobile phones have publicly routable IP addresses.  Most are behind NAT.

You may want to consider using C2DM instead:

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, there is no need for globally routable IP addresses, as there are RFC-compliant solutions for NAT-traversal (STUN, TURN, ICE, etc).